# how do I enable debug logs for triggers?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm debugging an issue now, I have managed to enable debug logs for **operators** by updating `airflow.cfg` with

```
[core]
logging_level = DEBUG
```

But I don't see any **trigger** logs in the task view. How can I enable it?